# Error to connect to database (Mysql) when publising shiny app

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

When running my shiny app locally everything works fine. However, when deployed (published) on "shinyapps.io", which is the free service, the application didn't work, because it was not able to connect to Mysql, as I checked on the logs from shinnyapps.

I used the "dplyr" library to make the connection. The server which I connect is not a cloud one, it is local.

```
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="USER", dbname = "DB", password = "XXXX", host = "192.168.6.6",port=3306)
```

The log erros showed the following error message:

```
Warning: Error in .local: Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.5' (110)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), 
  user="USER", dbname = "DB", password = "XXXX",
  host = "192.168.6.6",port=3306)
```

That host address, starting 192.168, is on your local subnet, possibly its your personal desktop or laptop. Your shiny app is running on a server in a data centre somewhere possibly on the other side of the planet. It needs your server's public IP address, not a local network address. Is your server available from outside your local network? Use that IP address and hope that the shiny server doesn't firewall outgoing connections.